# HTML, CSS: text align with display: inline not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website. Text-align: center does not work with display: inline-block but is there any way to my text-align to work with display: inline-block?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'Helvetica';
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
#my_cycle_head {
  text-align: center;
}
#main_navbar {
  text-align: center;
}
#main_navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
#main_navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="my_cycle_head">My Cycle</h1>
  <ul id="main_navbar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: which content specifically are you looking to center? Is it just the dropdown menu that you're having issues with?

Comment: i dont get you what you really want, maybe that?-> [DEMO](http://output.jsbin.com/fiqekuconu)

Comment: Did you try margin 0 auto;?

Comment: Yes i tried margin 0 auto

Comment: I mean to say is there a way to get text-align working  with display: inline

Comment: It's the links in the nav bar i want to be centered.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `display: inline`, the element resizes to the width of the content. There for there is no easy way to center it.

However, if you use `display: inline-block;` it combines the two, it is inline (no breaks before and after) but also can have a set width.

```
#main_navbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-right: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Based on the example you provided - it seems to work fine for me. What is the effect you're trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: To center the context of the links in the navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your links between the opening and closing div tag as follow:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="home-page.html">Homepage</a>
    <a href="contact-page.html">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work with the code provided and introducing inline styles along with stylesheets is a bad idea.